# Textbox width varies in chrome and internet explorer

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

there is an input textbox
input name="raiseOnBehalfOf"  style="width:196px;" disabled="true" id="raiseOnBehalfOf" type="text" value="somename"

in internet explorer, this width is looking fine. but in chrome textbox width shows 2px extra.
what is the solution to set the same width in IE and Chrome browser?
[image: picture from chrome here]
[image: picture from IE]

Comment: add height in input field

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different default widths, margins, borders, paddings etc. A text input has a smaller border and padding in Internet Explorer than in Chrome. I recommend always setting things like marigns, borders and paddings in CSS, even if it doesn't change anything in your browser, beacuse it may ensure it looks the same in other browsers.

Long story short: set the text input a given padding and border.

Comment: if we use padding-inline:0px; it is working fine in chrome browser. Thanks Mispell